# All declarations of 'CKEDITOR_VERSION' must have identical modifiers

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I followed step by step according to [official documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html) to make a text editor in angular so there were some build errors when I typed the command "ng serve".

[image: Image Description]

*What could be causing this error?*

**Or is the optimal way to use "ng2-ckeditor" instead of "ckeditor5"?**

I wanted to add *MathType* and *ChemType* plugins to CKEditor5. But I'm having trouble starting CKeditor. However, I used

> ng2-ckeditor

in my projects, but I couldn't find any material about adding MathType plugin to it.

Comment: **Temporary solution:**
Follow the link that has an error one by one and remove the null check for the CKEditor_Version field and make the type string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the below solution to get rid of this.

Open this file and comment out the version.

node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/ckeditor.component.d.ts

[image]

After comment this, you can build it properly

Answer (score 3):

I have raised this issue on CKEditor Github and it is now fixed. More info [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/342)